# codeigniter adding removing dynamic forms that contain image and href

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, codeigniter

I have this thing going on in my site thats the admin side:

[image]

Im using Codeigniter framework. And what I want to accomplish is to add and remove the `<li>` classes dynamically on click. Can someone suggest how can I do that? I did research and couldn't find anything. Any info or pointers to get me going would be greatly appreciated.

```
<pre>
    <li class="thumbnail span3">
          <div class="maxheight">
            <figure class="img-polaroid spinner"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/page-img.jpg" alt=""></figure>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $p1; ?><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/thumbnails-img.png"  alt=""><span></span></a>
          </div>
          <input value = "<?php echo $p1; ?>" type="text" name="p1">
    </li>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have syntax errors:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url();>
```

Should be:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```

And this:

```
<?php echo $p1 ?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php echo $p1; ?>
```

**Update:**
And for removing and adding elements in page you should use javscript.

Comment: Yes, but thats irrelevent to my question.

Comment: Also missing a closing quote on the `<img>`.